# Named Entity Recognition on Upper Case Text

Tags: nlp, opennlp, stanford-nlp

How to extract entities from upper case text.

I use - http://corenlp.run/

with test data - I KNOW TOM LIVES IN LONDON.

LONDON - Location
TOM - not identified
relation not identified

with test data - I know Tom lives in London.
Tom - Person
London - Location
relation correctly identified.

How to improve this?

Answer (score 3):

I have gone through the exact same problem that you had. The best approach for this is using your own Dictionary. It will be much much faster than using Stanford NER.

Here are some sources.

```
http://deron.meranda.us/data/census-dist-female-first.txt (4275 entries)
http://deron.meranda.us/data/census-dist-male-first.txt (1219 entries)
http://deron.meranda.us/data/census-derived-all-first.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the caseless model which ignores the case.  But make sure you are only using this on sentences that are all upper case or lower case for best results!

The caseless model is available in the English models jar.  You can download that model jar here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

You need to set the "ner.model" parameter to use the caseless models:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("ner.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz,edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.muc.7class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz,edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.conll.4class.caseless.distsim.crf.ser.gz");
```

I think it could be a cool new feature in the next NER system to automatically detect if the sentence is ALL-CAPS or all-lower-case and use a caseless model for those sentences.